# Characteristic polynomial and characteristic equation - connection?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we have a ODE of second order with constant coefficients, we make the ansatz $\lambda^2+a_1\lambda+a_2=0$ and solve it for $\lambda$.
This equation is called the characteristic equation.

Does this have anything to do with the characteristic polynomial whose zeros we are searching when looking for eigenvalues of a matrix, i.e. 
$$\det(A-\lambda E_n)=0?$$

Comment: I assume you mean $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ (what is $E_n$?).  It would be easier to answer if you described the second order ODE, I assume it is something like $x'' + a_1x' + a_2x=0$.  Indeed we can convert to a first-order vector-based system $\vec{x}' = A\vec{x}$ with a matrix $A$, and eigenvalues of $A$ are important.

Comment: $E_n$ is another notation to write $I_n$, unit matrix $n \times n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that any homogeneous ordinary differential equation of order $2$ boils down to a system of ordinary differential equations of order $1$. Indeed, one has: $$y''+a_1y'+a_2y=0\Leftrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-a_2 & -a_1\end{pmatrix}Y=Y'\textrm{, where }Y:=\begin{pmatrix}y\\y'\end{pmatrix}.$$
The characteristic polynomials of the $2\times 2$ matrix is precisely $X^2+a_1X+a_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a connection between linear algebra and differential equations. It has to do with the linearity of differentiation:

$$D(af(x)+bg(x)) = aD(f(x)) + bD(g(x))$$

So if we can connect $f$ and $g$ to vectors in some sense we can create a matrix that performs differentiation on these vectors, since matrix multiplication preserves the same properties:
$${\bf M(}a{\bf f}+b{\bf g}) = a{\bf Mf} + b{\bf Mg}$$

Then what would eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the matrix $\bf M$ mean?